# Django - Cannot link static CSS to applications

Tags: python, html, css, django, static

So I am working on a django datascience project tutorial from this guy's youtube channel: https://github.com/pyplane/django_with_data_science and I'm stuck at getting my static CSS file to apply to my html view.

here is my file structure:

So far, I've been able to get static_project/main.js to work fine but I cannot get the style.css file to work.

style.css

```
.test_blue_2 {
    color:blue;
    }
```

css_test.html

```
{% load static %}

<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href={% static 'style.css' %}>

<style type = 'text/css'>
     .test_blue_1 {
        color:blue;
        }
</style>

{% block content %}
    <div class ='test_blue_1'>Blue text 1</div>
    <div class ='test_blue_2'>Blue text 2</div>
{% endblock %}
```

This outputs Blue text 1 in blue and Blue text 2 remains black

Settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_project'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn", "static_root")

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn", "media_root")
```

http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/style.css yields

```
.test_blue_2 {
    color:blue;
    }
```

here is my file structure:

[image]

Comment: Look into resulting HTML, probably you just need to restart  runserver

Comment: I've restarted several times and it didn't help :(

Comment: you don't have  apostrophe around href attribute

Comment: Yup that was it. Second  time I've let something like that screw me up :(